# Difference between Angular Module Federation and Angular Elements

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-elements

Can anyone explain to me the difference between Angular Module Federation and Angular Elements? I am new to Angular and my understanding so far is that both are two ways to provide shared Web Components?

But is there a key reason to use one or the other? What are the differences or pros and cons between these approaches?

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this?